# Error when attempting to install Karma

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to install Karma using the following command:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install karma
```

However, I receive the following error when I attempt to install Karma on my Windows 8.1 machine:

```
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.2.0
\


> ws@0.4.31 install C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\karma\node_modules\sock
et.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

|
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\s
ocket.io-client\node_modules\ws>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\b
in\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
karma@0.12.17 node_modules\karma
├── di@0.0.1
├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── mime@1.2.11
├── q@0.9.7
├── chokidar@0.8.2 (recursive-readdir@0.0.2)
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
├── source-map@0.1.37 (amdefine@0.1.0)
├── lodash@2.4.1
├── log4js@0.6.15 (semver@1.1.4, async@0.1.15, readable-stream@1.0.27-1)
├── useragent@2.0.9 (lru-cache@2.2.4)
├── http-proxy@0.10.4 (pkginfo@0.3.0, utile@0.2.1)
├── connect@2.12.0 (uid2@0.0.3, methods@0.1.0, cookie-signature@1.0.1, debug@0.8
.1, pause@0.0.1, fresh@0.2.0, qs@0.6.6, bytes@0.2.1, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, raw-bod
y@1.1.2, batch@0.5.0, cookie@0.1.0, negotiator@0.3.0, send@0.1.4, multiparty@2.2
.0)
└── socket.io@0.9.17 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-c
lient@0.9.16)
```

Comment: I'm running into the same problem but installing on CentOS. I think the root of the issue is that fsevents is for Mac events: https://www.npmjs.org/package/fsevents

Comment: I don't see any error in the output there. Can you be more specific about what you're seeing that makes you think an error has occurred? (The output does show a warning on Windows, but I have never seen that warning be a real indication of a problem.)

Comment: Hi, please pick the answer for this question.. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there are any errors.

Just need to install karma-cli

```
npm install -g karma-cli
```

Then karma should work.

Comment: There is probably nothing in "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\karma\node_modules\sock
et.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws" so it fails on build

Comment: In my case there is this directory with files yet its failing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case the solution to the problem was to use the command in the right folder. I was one folder in hierarchy below where I should have been.